# Two Independent Docker-Compose-Files And Access To Shared Folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elastic-stack

**Hello Community!**

I've ran to following problem and dis not find any helpful advices in documentations:

I have two `docker-compose.yml` files. Let's assume this case:

**File 1:**

```
docker-compose-application.yml
```

- Contains ceveral services and configurations.

**File 2:**

```
docker-compose-elasticstack.yml
```

- Contains Services ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana and FileBeat

Both files are startable indpendently and working properly. Normally I start only the application. Only in some special cases the elastistack is necessary too.

**Question:**

How can I configure an optional fileshare for the logs between these two files, that I can access with FileBeat? So if necessary I start both files, if not only the application.

**Goal: 1**

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-application.yml up
```

- Application running without shared log file directory.

**Goal: 2**

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-application.yml -f docker-compose-elasticstack.yml up
```

- Application + Elasticstack running with shared log file directory.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *external named* volume:

docker-compose-application.yml:

```
services:
  app:
    image: app-image
    volumes:
      - logs:/path/in/container

volumes:
  logs:
    external: true
```

docker-compose-elasticstack.yml

```
services:
  filebeat:
    image: filebeat-image
    volumes:
      - logs:/path/in/container
  ... other services

volumes:
  logs:
    external: true
```

Note that this named volume needs to exist before you `docker-compose up`. 
You can create it via `docker volume create logs`.

See further information [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external).

Comment: Is it possible that it is not shared "live"? Because unfortunately I can not see the logs, only after restart.

Comment: The volume is certainly shared "live". As soon as your application flushes a line of log to disk (logs-volume) filebeat should see it.